# Access property inside another model

Tags: c#

I have a simple model inside another model like this:

First Model

```
public class ReminderPushNotificationTest
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    ....
    public ReminderPushNotificationAndroidResult AndroidResult{ get; set; }
}
```

Second model

```
public class ReminderPushNotificationAndroidResult
{
    public string Headers { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to fill model I try something like:

```
var testModel = new ReminderPushNotificationTest
{
    UserName = username,
    AndroidResult.{Want property inside this model} = result.Header
}
```

How can I access that property to assign it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an instance of second model before filling it's properties likewise you have created instance for the base model class

```
var testModel = new ReminderPushNotificationTest
{
   UserName = username,
   AndroidResult = new ReminderPushNotificationAndroidResult
   {
       Headers = result.Header,
       Content = "abcd"  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var testModel = new ReminderPushNotificationTest
{
    UserName = username,
    AndroidResult = new ReminderPushNotificationAndroidResult
    {
        Headers = result.Header
    }
}
```

You can't set a property for an object that hasn't yet been instantiated.